# std::localtime returning null

Tags: c++, time, posix

I have an amount of seconds since 1 of january of year 2000. 
Im trying to build a std::tm structure with it. 
To do so, I try:

```
//seconds from 1970 to 2000.
unsigned long long secstoposix = 946684800; 
//secsfromdate is the amount of secs since 2000...
unsigned long long l=secstoposix + secsfromdate;

this->time=l; //(posix+amount)
tm=*std::localtime(&time);  // <-- std::localtime returns null.
```

localtime returns null and errno is set to 0, so I don't get what is failing here.

Comment: You should know the drill by now. Please provide a complete, verifiable, and minimal example.

Comment: Considering that we won't roll over a signed 32-bit integer until [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) (right now the time is `1571315180` on my system), the value `18446744073709551615` seems awfully large.

Comment: yes, I copied it from a bad place. I edited.

Comment: The check `sizeof(time_t)` and compare it to `sizeof(unsigned long long)`. And enable more warning from the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `18446744073709551615` is `2^64 - 1` which is not the number of seconds from 1970 to 2000.

`std::time_t` is implementation defined, on my machine it is a signed 64 bit integer. Thus, `std::time_t time = l;` might overflow which might be the reason for `std::localtime` returning `nullptr`.